# Have RCT3 retail on my PC, bought RCT3: Platinum from Steam. How should I set up?

Tags: steam, rollercoaster-tycoon-3

I've had a retail copy of RollerCoaster Tycoon 3 since it first came out, which was several years ago. It's a great game. I don't play it as regularly as other games, but I still love it.

The other day [there was a Steam Daily Deal](http://store.steampowered.com/news/6388) on RCT3: Platinum (RCT3 + Soaked! + Wild!). I went ahead and grabbed a copy because I don't have the expansions, there was no way to purchase each individual expansion via Steam, and 10 bucks seemed a good deal in my book anyway. Also, I like the Steam platform.

My save games and other data are probably going to be compatible two expansions up, so I'm not worried about those, but what do I do with my existing RCT3 installation itself? Do I need to get rid of that first before having Steam install RCT3: Platinum?

Comment: I realize Steam installs games in the steamapps folder, but I'm not sure if any unexpected conflicts are going to happen, so I thought I'd stop by and see if anyone knows better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run into no problems.  If you're hurting for disk space, you could delete it, but your OS knows which one is which and they are not sharing resources.